# Ifinstring: locate variable number after text then randomly Send new number +/- 20 of that #

Tags: random, autohotkey

I have a very simple AHK script that reads a log.txt every so often and then randomly generates numbers within a range when the triggering text is found then Sends the random number as my guess.  It's for a stupid lottery type thing.

The thing is, if the previous winning number was, for instance, 40, then it's seemingly never within 20 numbers of 40 again the next time around, so I'm trying to figure out how to locate the number 40 immediately after my Ifinstring trigger, then randomly generate (and then Send,) a single number between 0 and 20 as well as 60 to 100.  I'm sure there's plenty of efficient ways to do this but I'm new and would like a simple way.  It's just a macro really, and I'm just a newbie trying to optimize my one script.

Thanks for the patience and help :)

Comment: Could you please improved your question?

Comment: Please show your code (or an outline of same, if it is verbose), so we can determine where you are going wrong.

Comment: Without more information, there is no way I can help.